# Character Arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am a beginner in C Programming Language, I am very confused about the null character (`'\0'`) in the C Programming Language.

Based on the program below, the allowed character length for a line is `10` (`MAXLINE` is defined to `10`). An input like `Navindren` of length 9 occupies array indices `0` to `8`, whenever a new line character is reached it is added to the index `9` and `i` is incremented by `1`. `i` is `10` now and `s[10]` is assigned with the `'\0'`, `s[10] = '\0'`.

Here is the confusion, how is this possible since the array is only allocated space from the index `0`- `9` ? I tried referring to many online resources but the explanations are not sufficient.

Main Function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

main() {
    int len;                /*current line length*/
    int max;                /*maximum length seen so far*/
    char line[MAXLINE];     /*current input line*/
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /*longest line saved here*/

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        printf("%d\n", len);
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */ {
        printf("%s", longest);
    } else {
        printf("No Lines Detected\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Getline Function:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
            s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = '\n';
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Copy function:

```
/*copy: copy `from` into `to`; assume to is big enough*/
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;
    i = 0;

    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `s[10]`, which is `lines[10]`, must not be accessed (no read nor wrote) because it is out-of-range. Accessing it will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "how is this possible" because your C compiler is too lazy to generate code to check if the index is out-of-range? Anything may happen when *undefined behavior* is invoked.

Comment: That means it will not display an error ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour means "undefined behaviour". There is no reason why it should do anything at all.

Comment: You may want to start by compiling with all reasonable compiler warnings enabled. For example, your `getline()` doesn't even use its second argument.

Comment: @naveenath There is very likely unused memory at `s[10]`, so things appear to work. But they might not, if you for example change the code in any way, or change compiler options like optimization level. This is what *undefined behavior* means: anything can happen, including things seemingly working at the moment.

Comment: @MikeCAT Calling C compiler "lazy", if it doesn't generate bounds checking code is... *very* misleading, to put it charitably.

Comment: Be aware that there is a POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
and this may cause you problems with your function — not least because the interfaces are different.  Note that you pass `lim` to the function, but you don't then use it (you use MAXLINE instead).  This is a bad idea.  If you're going to add the newline and null, you need to reserve space for them; that means you must use 'limit - 2' rather than 'limit - 1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getline` function stops either when `i` reaches `9` or when the next byte read from the file is a `'\n'`.  You cannot have both conditions true at the end of the loop, hence the `'\n'` is only added if `i` is less than `9`, so invalid position `s[10]` is never stored into.

Let's assume the input file contains the bytes:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| N | a | v | i | n | d | r | e | n |\n |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Here are the steps executed by `getline()`:

- `i = 0` (loop initialisation statement, executed once)
- `i < 9` -> true
- `c = getchar()` -> `c` receives `'N'`
- `c != EOF` -> true
- `c != '\n'` -> true
- `s[i] = c` -> `s[0]` receives `'N'`
- `i++` -> `i` is now `1`

The loop repeats the above steps until `s[8]` receives `'n'` and `i` is incremented to `9`.

The final steps are:

- `i < 9` -> false, loop is exited.
- `if (c == '\n')` -> false, `c` contains `'n'`, not `'\n'`, the linefeed has not been read. `if` branch is skipped.
- `s[i] = '\n'` -> `s[9]` receives the null byte, `'\0'`.
- `return i;` -> the value `9` is returned to the caller.

There is indeed a problem in your implementation of `getline()`: you pass an argument for the size of the destination array but the code uses a hardcoded value `MAXLINE` instead.

Aside from this issue, the behavior is quite similar to that of `fgets()`.  Did you intend it this way or did you intend to read the line without the trailing linefeed, as the obsolete unsafe function `gets()` used to do?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the questions, what will happen when the input for example is a string "Navindren", can you debug the code using this input and tell me clearly what you observe.

Comment: this answer already gives you a hint, the "debug the code" part is your own job